# FDR and Bonferroni corrections. Alternative calculation methods?

Tags: python, p-value, bonferroni

I have two questions:

First: I was just wondering if there is another way to calculate FDR (or other pvalue correction methods) besides using statsmodels.stats.multitest.multipletests?

Especially I am looking for FDR as stand alone (for example NOT frd_bh) which - as far as I have seen - is not given here.

Second: In which cases are the corrected and adjusted p-values always the same among all methods when using stats.multitest? It happened in my case (352 tests, alpha=0.05) where the adjusted p-value is always like the bonferroni correction definition (alpha/number of tests) 0.05/352 - I am wondering what I did wrong.

Thank you for all answers!!

Answer (score 0):

An answer to your first question is [`scipy.stats.false_discovery_control`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.false_discovery_control.html).